# Calculating primitive roots

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Wikipedia cleanly demonstrates that $3$ is a primitive root modulo $7$. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n#Elementary_example)
is the table, and my question is how do they calculate the 4th column? It appears that they take the exponent from the previous column and multiply it by $3$ but this pattern fails for the 4th row.

1. Is there some number theoretic result that allows this to be calculated so seamlessly? If not what am I not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the fourth column, they reduce $3^n$ modulo $7$ to make computations easier. As an example, $3^3=27$ which is $=6\mod 7$ for $27-6=21=3\times 7$.

Remember that by construction of $\equiv$ in $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$, if $a\equiv b\mod n$ and $a'\equiv b'\mod n$ then $a+a'\equiv b+b'\mod n$ and $aa'\equiv bb'\mod n$.

Comment: $3^3 = 27$ which is $6\mod 7$ seems just like a brute force calculation to me...

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus What do you mean by "brute force calculation"?

Comment: It seems like you would just compute $3^3$ then find $27\mod 7$. Perhaps there is nothing more to it than that. Larger numbers are harder to computer because I don't know multiples of numbers greater than $12$. I can compute $3^4\mod 7 = 4$ pretty quickly only because I know that $12*7 = 84$ otherwise I wouldn't know what to do. This led me to think that this table was doing something more clever.

Comment: Well, $3^4=81$, and $81=11\mod 7$ by subtracting $70$. Then $11=4\mod 7$. If you want to be more economic, $3^2=9=2\mod 7$, so $3^4=3^23^2=2\cdot 2=4$.